# env variables in node js

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I'm trying to access some env variables from a javascript server file, where both files are in the same folder, but the data I get is 'undefined' and I don't get the data itself. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const express = require("express");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: `Hello from server! ${spotifyApi.clientId}----${process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID}`,
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Node dependencies:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "spotify-web-api-node": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: The env file in this case should be in the root directory same as package.json. Are those in heirarchy? Or pass the file path to dotenv where your env file is located

Comment: Where have you placed the `.env` file?

Comment: I have a root dir with a package.json file, and 2 other folders: 1 for react and one for express (frontend/backend), and in each of those folders are their respective package.json files. the code is from the express folder and in that same folder is the .env file.